# How to select each option elements from select html element by using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html select element, which has include three option html elements as children.
I have the following JQuery code:

```
jQuery('[name=element_1] option[value="value_1"]').attr('title', 'Tooltip for value_1'); 
jQuery('[name=element_1] option[value="value_2"]').attr('title', 'Tooltip for value_2');
jQuery('[name=element_1] option[value="value_3"]').attr('title', 'Tooltip for value_3');
```

I would like to set a title attribute for each available option html element of the select html element. It is important, that each option element must be get a specific title attribute. The the code above nothing happens.

I have written this jQuery Code before, and title attributes was set, but each option element get the title attribute "Tooltip for value_3" and this is not the aim:

```
 jQuery('[name=element_1]').val("value_1").attr('title', 'Tooltip for value_1') ; 
 jQuery('[name=element_1]').val("value_2").attr('title', 'Tooltip for value_2') ;
 jQuery('[name=element_1]').val("value_3").attr('title', 'Tooltip for value_3') ;
```

How can I implement this in JQuery?

The HTML Code:

```
<select id="element_1" name="element_1">
   <option value="value_1">value_1</option>
   <option value="value_2">value_2</option>
   <option value="value_3">value_3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: well make a demonstration..!

Comment: Could you share us your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about presetting an object with the tooltips using the options values as keys, as such:

```
var tooltips = {
    'value_1': 'Tooltip for value_1',
    'value_2': 'Tooltip for value_2',
    'value_3': 'Tooltip for value_3'
};

$('#element_1 option').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', tooltips[$(this).val()]);
});
```

**[Code Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gfn8T/)**

Comment: Sorry but this kind of code set "Tooltip for value_3" for each option element ! Please look at my first code example above. This creates the same result.

Comment: No reason why this wouldn't work unless you overlooked something.

Comment: You are right, your code snippet works ! Sorry, it was my mistake

Comment: I have a question again, could you please answer me, why this jquery selector doesn´t work: var jQuerySelektor = "'[name=" + NameSelectElement + "] option'";
  jQuery(jQuerySelektor).each(function() {
      $(this).attr('title', tooltiplist[$(this).val()]);
  });  Many Thanks !!!

Comment: There's no reason to use wrapping quotes twice. `var jQuerySelektor = "[name=" + NameSelectElement + "] option";` I removed the single quotes from the selector.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
jQuery("[name=element_1] option").each(function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('title', "Tooltip for " + jQuery(this).val());
});
```

Comment: OK my code example is too easy. The value for the title attribute is in my application much complexer as i posted here in the forum. So you code doesn´t work. I need a own solution for each available option element !

Comment: The jquery function "nth-child()" is a good way, but i don´t know, how to combine this the my select parent element

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your second snippet works at all. The reason it doesn't work right is because you're not selecting each child element of `<select>`. To target its children specifically, you want JQuery's find function:

```
jQuery('[name=element_1]').find(jQuery('[value=value_1]').attr('title', 'Tooltip for value_1')); 
jQuery('[name=element_1]').find(jQuery('[value=value_2]').attr('title', 'Tooltip for value_2'));
jQuery('[name=element_1]').find(jQuery('[value=value_3]').attr('title', 'Tooltip for value_3'));
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6aX6/)**